# What's the right way to include a file to an android app?

Tags: android, file

I'm using [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/index.html) to do some classification in an android app. I wanted to build a classifier and train it with some training data from a `.arff` file, when I asked myself the question where that file should go.

I'm quite a newbie to android and I know how to work with the external storage, so that would solve the problem, but I don't feel well about it. The idea would be to reference some file on the external storage and then store that file in the external storage from my computer, but this seems very unpractical and unsafe.

My question is thus: how do I include a file (which is necessary to make the app work) in a right way? Preferably so that I do not have to worry whether I put the right place and that it is just included in the `.apk` in the end if that would be possible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a folder called `raw` inside your `res` folder. Then put the file in there. Then the file will be accessible in your code by calling:

`InputStream inputStream = getResources.openRawResource(R.raw.your_file_name);`

Comment: Is it worth mentioning assets and the AssetManager?